# How to select entire text (number) in Infragistics XamNumericEditor after receive Focus?

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics

in my project I have Infragistics *XamTextEditor* and *XamNumericEditor*. I want when the users TAB to a control or click on it, the entire text or number to be selected. In XamTextEditor it works, but for XamNumericEditor not.

Is possible select entire number in XamNumericEditor or is this possible only for XamTextEditor?

Answer (score 2):

Use the SelectAll method in EditModStarted event. An example I use:

```
                igEditors:XamNumericEditor EditModeStarted="ComparisonFontSize_EditModeStarted"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    BorderBrush="LightGray"
                    Margin="105,31,0,0" 
                    Name="ComparisonFontSize" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Mask="nn" Width="40" SpinButtonDisplayMode="Always"
```

in the code put:

```
    private void ComparisonFontSize_EditModeStarted(object sender, Infragistics.Windows.Editors.Events.EditModeStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComparisonFontSize.SelectAll();
    }
```